# Calculate the fastest 5 KM time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a cycling computer logging every second how far I've gone

A simplified version of the data looks like this:

```
public class TrackPoint
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public virtual DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public virtual double DistanceMeters { get; set; }
}

var trackPointList = new List<TrackPoint>
{
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:48"), DistanceMeters = 3.8099999427795410},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:49"), DistanceMeters = 7.7600002288818359},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:50"), DistanceMeters = 12.3299999237060547},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:51"), DistanceMeters = 18.0000000000000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:52"), DistanceMeters = 24.8999996185302734},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:53"), DistanceMeters = 32.1599998474121094},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:54"), DistanceMeters = 40.7200012207031250},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:55"), DistanceMeters = 49.7599983215332031},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:57"), DistanceMeters = 68.6100006103515625},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:58"), DistanceMeters = 79.3199996948242188},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:18:00"), DistanceMeters = 100.1900024414062500},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:18:02"), DistanceMeters = 122.7099990844726563},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:18:03"), DistanceMeters = 134.1900024414062500},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:18:04"), DistanceMeters = 145.9199981689453125},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:18:05"), DistanceMeters = 158.4700012207031250},

    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:04"), DistanceMeters = 5003.4101562500000000}, //5000 meters driven
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:05"), DistanceMeters = 5018.7797851562500000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:06"), DistanceMeters = 5034.0498046875000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:07"), DistanceMeters = 5048.8901367187500000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:08"), DistanceMeters = 5063.8798828125000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:09"), DistanceMeters = 5079.0200195312500000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:13"), DistanceMeters = 5141.0600585937500000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:17"), DistanceMeters = 5201.7500000000000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:21"), DistanceMeters = 5261.8798828125000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:23"), DistanceMeters = 5290.2900390625000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:28"), DistanceMeters = 5363.7099609375000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:33"), DistanceMeters = 5435.9101562500000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:34"), DistanceMeters = 5450.8901367187500000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:35"), DistanceMeters = 5465.4199218750000000},
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:36"), DistanceMeters = 5480.5400390625000000},
};
```

For each record after 5KM are driven I' would like to calculate the time used for the last 5km.

My problem are for each record after 5000 meters to locate the record closest to 5000 meters before. I have looked at the `MinBy`  extention from MoreLinq, but I'm unsure if it is the way ahead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto hang on I'll update the question ..

Comment: As a side note, your code would be a lot more concise and readable with a helper method or constructor accepting a string and a double, and returning a `TrackPoint`.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right. The code above where auto generated from my database.

Comment: Which may be fine for other purposes, but if the aim is to provide a [mcve], it's worth taking the time to change it to be as simple as possible.

Comment: How much do you care about efficiency? The answers so far are fairly inefficient, but simple - that may be fine for you, or it may not be. Please indicate that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping things simple, you could just keep track of the last point you found closest to a mark:

```
var trackPointList = new List<TrackPoint>
{
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:17:48"), DistanceMeters = 3.8099999427795410},
    // ...
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:24:04"), DistanceMeters = 5003.4101562500000000}, //5000 meters driven
    // ...
    new TrackPoint {Time = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-10 07:30:04"), DistanceMeters = 10003.4101562500000000}, //10000 meters driven
};

// determine how many marks you have according to the highest value recorded
int pointsCount = (int)trackPointList[trackPointList.Count - 1].DistanceMeters % 5000;

var lastPoint = trackPointList[0];

for (int i = 1; i < pointsCount; i++)
{
    double point = i * 5000;
    // find the closest to the current mark
    var currentPoint = trackPointList.Where(x => x.DistanceMeters > point).First();

    Console.WriteLine("At {0}, you have driven {1}, {2} for the past 5KM", currentPoint.Time, currentPoint.DistanceMeters, currentPoint.Time - lastPoint.Time);

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

which prints:

```
At 10/08/2018 07:24:04, you have driven 5003.41015625, 00:06:16 for the past 5KM
At 10/08/2018 07:30:04, you have driven 10003.41015625, 00:06:00 for the past 5KM
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding this method to your trackpoint class you can get the previous based on a user defined distance (returns null if nothing found)

```
public class TrackPoint
        {
            public virtual Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
            public virtual DateTime Time { get; set; }
            public virtual double DistanceMeters { get; set; }

            public TrackPoint GetPreviousByDistance(double Distance, List<TrackPoint> TrackPointsPoints)
            {
                TrackPoint prevTrackpoint = null;
                double prevDistance = this.DistanceMeters - Distance;
                if (prevDistance > 0)
                {
                    prevTrackpoint = TrackPointsPoints.Where(tp => tp.DistanceMeters < prevDistance).OrderByDescending(tp => tp.DistanceMeters).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                return prevTrackpoint;
            }
        }
```

Once you've located the correct trackpoint, you can do whatever calculation you want to work out time & distance and adjust to a 5000m time if required.

Usage:

```
 TrackPoint ThisTrackPoint = trackPointList[22]; //Or however you want to define it
 TrackPoint PreviosTrackPoint = ThisTrackPoint.GetPreviousByDistance(5000, trackPointList);  // Can change distance as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

...

  Dictionary<TrackPoint, TimeSpan> TimeSpans = new Dictionary<TrackPoint, TimeSpan>();

  foreach (var trackpoint in trackPointList.Where(x => x.DistanceMeters >= 5000))
  {
    double distance = trackpoint.DistanceMeters;
    foreach (var trackpoint2 in trackPointList.Where(x => x.DistanceMeters < distance).Reverse())
    {
      if (trackpoint2.DistanceMeters <= distance - 5000)
      {
        TimeSpans.Add(trackpoint, trackpoint.Time - trackpoint2.Time);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

This works for me.
I'm looping through all trackpoints where the distance is > 5000. Then I go back and look what time 5000 meters before was.